App gets stuck on getServiceStatusStream()
In my Flutter app project, I'm working to track whether the user’s location services are enabled or disabled, using the Bloc architecture.
Initially, I used the Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled() method, but I discovered that it only checks the location status at the start of the app. I then tried using the Geolocator.getServiceStatusStream() method; however, it doesn't check the location status during app startup.
I also attempted combining these two methods, which worked correctly initially. However, when I toggled the location services on or off afterward, the app would freeze at that point.
The app should first check if location services are enabled using Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled() during the initial state. Based on this check, it will trigger the appropriate state in the Bloc. If location services are initially disabled, emitting a LocationDisabledState, a dialog box will appear, prompting the user to enable location services.
At this point, Geolocator.getServiceStatusStream() will start tracking any changes in location status. If the user enables location services, the stream will trigger a LocationEnabledState, which will automatically close the dialog box. This approach ensures that the dashboard responds dynamically to both the initial and any subsequent changes in the location service status.
I provided my Bloc code and dashboard page code—please help me resolve this issue
@immutable
sealed class LocationStatusEvent {}
class StartCheckingLocationStatusEvent extends LocationStatusEvent{}

This code are my bloc files:
@immutable
sealed class LocationStatusState {}
final class LocationStatusInitial extends LocationStatusState {}
final class LocationDisabledState extends LocationStatusState {}
final class LocationEnabledState extends LocationStatusState {}
final class LocationErrorState extends LocationStatusState {}

class LocationStatusBloc extends Bloc<LocationStatusEvent, LocationStatusState> {
  LocationStatusBloc() : super(LocationStatusInitial()) {
    on<StartCheckingLocationStatusEvent>(checkLocation);
  }
 Future<void> checkLocation(
    StartCheckingLocationStatusEvent event,
    Emitter<LocationStatusState> emit,
  ) async {
    try {
  
      final bool isEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
      if(isEnabled){
        emit(LocationEnabledState());
      }else if(!isEnabled){
        emit(LocationDisabledState());
      }
      Geolocator.getServiceStatusStream().listen((status) {
        emit(status == ServiceStatus.enabled
            ? LocationEnabledState()
            : LocationDisabledState());
      });
    } catch (e) {
      emit(LocationErrorState());
    }
  }
}

This code is my dashboard page:
class DashboardScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DashboardScreen({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocListener(
        listeners: [
          BlocProvider(create: (_) => BnbBloc()),
          BlocListener<LocationStatusBloc, LocationStatusState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is LocationDisabledState) {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                barrierDismissible: false,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: const Text("Location Disabled"),
                    content: const Text("Please turn on location to use this app."),
                    actions: [
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          await Geolocator.openLocationSettings(); 
                        },
                        child: const Text("Turn on Location"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              );
            } else if (state is LocationEnabledState) {
              // Close dialog if it was open
              if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }
              // Trigger DashboardLocationBloc to fetch location
              
            }
          },
        ),
        ],
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(1, 7, 19, 1),
          appBar: AppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 70.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            flexibleSpace: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Color.fromARGB(255, 198, 28, 16), // Deep red
                    Color.fromARGB(248, 142, 20, 12), // Dark red
                    Color.fromRGBO(1, 7, 19, 1),
                    Color.fromRGBO(1, 7, 19, 1),
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            elevation: 0,
            title: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                BlocBuilder<DashboardInfoBloc, DashboardInfoState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    String name = "";
                    if (state is DashboardInfoLoadedState) {
                      name = state.userName;
                    } else if (state is DashboardInfoLoadingState) {
                      name = "-------";
                    }
                    return Text("Hi, $name!",
                        style: GoogleFonts.itim(
                            textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 19,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(214, 255, 255, 255))));
                  },
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.location_on,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(153, 33, 149, 243),
                      size: 17,
                    ),
                    BlocBuilder<LocationStatusBloc, LocationStatusState>(
                      builder: (context, state) {
                        String text = "";
                        if(state is LocationDisabledState){
                          
                          text = "Disabled";
                        }else if(state is LocationEnabledState){
                          text = "enabled";
                        }
                        return Text(
                          text,
                          style: GoogleFonts.itim(
                              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 13,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(222, 255, 255, 255))),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            actions: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 198, 28, 16),
                          spreadRadius: 0.5,
                          offset: Offset.fromDirection(2))
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(49),
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [
                        Colors.grey.shade800,
                        Colors.grey.shade600,
                      ],
                      begin: Alignment.topRight,
                      end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Material(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(49),
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                    color: Colors
                        .transparent, // Set to transparent to see gradient
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      splashColor: Colors.black38,
                      child: Ink(
                        height: 40,
                        width: 47,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(27, 0, 0, 0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(49)),
                        ),
                        child: const Image(
                          image: AssetImage("assets/icons/user.png"),
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 20,
                color: const Color.fromRGBO(1, 7, 19, 1),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 17, right: 17),
                child: Container(
                  height: 55,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(spreadRadius: 0.5, color: Colors.red)
                    ],
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(1, 7, 19, 1),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: SearchBar(
                      hintStyle: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
                          GoogleFonts.itim(color: Colors.grey.shade300)),
                      backgroundColor: const WidgetStatePropertyAll(
                          Color.fromARGB(14, 255, 255, 255)),
                      hintText: "search..",
                      leading: const Icon(
                        Icons.search_outlined,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(132, 224, 224, 224),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: BlocBuilder<BnbBloc, BnbState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return Center(
                      child: bottomNavScreen.elementAt(state.tabIndex),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BlocBuilder<BnbBloc, BnbState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              return BottomNavigationBar(
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(1, 7, 19, 1),
                items: bottomNavigationBarItem,
                currentIndex: state.tabIndex,
                selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
                unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
                iconSize: 20,
                selectedLabelStyle: GoogleFonts.itim(),
                unselectedLabelStyle: GoogleFonts.itim(),
                onTap: (index) {
                  BlocProvider.of<BnbBloc>(context)
                      .add(TabChangeEvent(tabIndex: index));
                },
              );
            },
          ),
     ));
  }
}

I also tried the above method, but when I run the app, it gets stuck at the initial stage:
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
part 'location_status_event.dart';
part 'location_status_state.dart';
class LocationStatusBloc extends Bloc<LocationStatusEvent, LocationStatusState> {
  StreamSubscription<ServiceStatus>? _locationServiceStatusSubscription;
  LocationStatusBloc() : super(LocationStatusInitial()) {
    on<StartCheckingLocationStatusEvent>(_checkInitialLocationStatus);
  }
  Future<void> _checkInitialLocationStatus(
      StartCheckingLocationStatusEvent event, Emitter<LocationStatusState> emit) async {
    try {
      // Check initial location service status
      bool isLocationEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
      if (isLocationEnabled) {
        emit(LocationEnabledState());
      } else {
        emit(LocationDisabledState());
      }

      // Start listening for location service status changes
      _locationServiceStatusSubscription =
          Geolocator.getServiceStatusStream().listen((ServiceStatus status) {
        if (status == ServiceStatus.enabled) {
          emit(LocationEnabledState());
        } else if (status == ServiceStatus.disabled) {
          emit(LocationDisabledState());
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      emit(LocationErrorState());
    }
  }
Stream<ServiceStatus> getServiceStatusStreamWithCurrentStatus() async* {
  yield await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled()
      .then((isEnabled) => isEnabled ? ServiceStatus.enabled : ServiceStatus.disabled);
  yield* Geolocator.getServiceStatusStream();
}

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _locationServiceStatusSubscription?.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}

Please help me solve this problem
